# How to use foreach loop to edit some rows while populating datatable from sql?

Tags: c#

I am trying to populate a **data table** from a database table. After it is populated i am using asp:GridView to show the data.

The problem is I am trying to edit some rows after it is populated from the database but before binding the data.

I am very new to c# so i cant get it working. My code does not update anything.

```
private void BindGridviewFileData()
{
    string ConnectionStringName = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
       using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringName))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM VISUALISATION";
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader objDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();
                objDataTable.Load(objDataReader);

                foreach (DataRow row in objDataTable.Rows)
                    if (row["lineNumber"] == "1")
                        row["BATCH_NO"] = "new Value";

                gvSubjectDetails.DataSource = objDataTable;
                gvSubjectDetails.DataBind();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Is this as simple as `if ((int)row["lineNumber"] == 1)` ?

Comment: What about if row["lineNumber"] was a string? Say i want to match row["BATCH_NO"]

Comment: What you have looks reasonable, so I can only assume that no row matches. Hence my point that maybe the problem is simply that equality test. So; is there a row with `lineNumber` something like `"1"`? And if there is: what *type* is it? What is `objDataTable.Columns["lineNumber"].ColumnType`, for example?

Comment: `if ((int)row["lineNumber"] == 1)` works perfect. `lineNumber` is an int. `row["BATCH_NO"]` is nvarchar(50). How can i check for `if (row["BATCH_NO"] == "some value")`

Comment: `BATCH_NO` addressed in the answer I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lineNumber` check probably needs to be an `int` check; note that currently it is actually doing an `object` check, which only supports reference equality - it will never match, even if the value is a `string` of `"1"`, because the value from the database will become a different `string` instance than the interned literal `"1"` from the code. So, the first check probably needs to be:

```
if((int)row["lineNumber"] == 1)
```

You ask in comments how to do this with a string; in that case, quite similarly:

```
if((string)row["BATCH_NO"] == "some value")
```

This now works because there is an overloaded `==` operator for `string==string`, which does a *value based* equality test, not a reference-based equality test.

Note: you could *also* probably use:

```
if(Equals(row["BATCH_NO"], "some value"))
```

but I find the earlier version clearer.